# Display Live Current Datetime

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

Is there any chance to display **live (real-time)** `Datetime` in `TextBlock` using `MVVM` or just `XAML` Binding or any other way in Windows Universal App?

Comment: Can you specify better what you need and show what you have tried? What do you mean by real-time (seconds, minutes, days)? Also what time zone? It's surely possible to create a property that will be updated with a timer.

Comment: @Romasz the current approach I have is displaying datetime using `timestamp_txt.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");`
 on each navigation to page `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)`, what I want is displaying the same, but live (not only on navigation to the page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very basic sample (needs some more work, especially on stopping/starting timer when needed). XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LiveTime, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="18"/>
```

and code behind:

```cs
public string LiveTime => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
    timer.Tick += (s, e) => RaiseProperty(nameof(LiveTime));
    timer.Start();
}
```